# Dynamic CSS grid with template-columns: auto and full-width row

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a CSS grid dynamically from some data. I'm trying to achieve a layout like:

```
   | a | b | c | d
---+---+---+---+---
full width
---+---+---+---+--
 x | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
---+---+---+---+--
 y | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

Where I have a dynamic number of columns, and a full width row that spans all of the columns.

The markup I'm generating (in a loop in my template) ends up looking something like:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">header 1</div>
  <div class="box header">header 2</div>
  <div class="box header">header 3</div>
  <div class="box header">header 4</div>
  <div class="box full-width">full width</div>
</div>
```

And I'm attempting to style it by marking the full-width row with:

```
    .full-width {
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
```

My understanding is that the `1 / -1` is supposed to make the row span from the first column to the last. In this case, it doesn't, and the width of the row is unaffected. You can see this issue [live on Codepen](https://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/VwWKLwQ).

Comment: it's the case but only for the explicit columns. You defined only one column with your template so the 1/-1 will fill it. The other one are the implicit ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `header` rule sets row to 1, and this limits your grid layout. You need at least 3 rows in order to have one for the header, and two for the full-width element.

1. Start by removing the `header` rule completely.
2. Then add grid-template-rows to the wrapper.
3. Change your wrapper to use `repeat()`, this makes the horizontal span work as expected:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
```

4. In order to make `full-width` span 2 rows you need at least 3 rows in total. Plus you need to declare your grid-row span like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.full-width {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

5. If you want an empty node at the top left corner of the grid, we need to increase the amount of columns to 5. We also need an extra class that pushes the first grid child one column towards the right (the other children will be pushed along):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.wrapper:first-child {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

Comment: *which makes an infinite amount of columns* --> it makes only one *explicit* column and other rules are creating more columns (the implicit one) as needed. It doesn't create an infinite amount

Comment: Thanks for your comment, doesn't it create as many columns as you have child elements in the grid parent? That was what I tried to say. But I may have misunderstood this.

Comment: no, the use of grid-row:1 is doing this. By placing all the items at the first row, the browser is obliged to create more columns that we call implicit columns but initially we only have one explicit column and grid-column:1/-1 consider only the explicit columns

Comment: Ah right, I missed the header rule with the grid-row: 1. Will update the answer.

Comment: I don't know how many columns I'm going to have, as they're dynamically created from the db. Is there a way to do this without hard coding the number of columns?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to spit out the CSS programmatically for this. Inline styles in JavaScript would be the easiest to work with here.